# Is there any way to prevent lights in linked files from behaving very differently?

Tags: light, linked-data

This is a light setup to imitate sun coming in through beams in a large space. In the working file there is a lot more going on but this is enough to talk about the issue. I don't think the particular light setup is the issue, but just in case, I'm including it. The file is attached.

[image: how area lights appear in an interior scene]

This is how that light setup looks if you link the collection everything is in to a new file.

[image: much brighter lights when the same setup is linked into a new file]

Now, I had hoped to link in a bunch of buildings into a much larger scene, so that it is easier to make changes to individual buildings and to use them in other ways. Does this mean that can't work? Is there a way around this? Are we going to have to either append everything or build all lights in the master scene?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instanced light don't cast shadows in 2.80, EEVEE doesn't support casting shadows from duplis (particles, collection instances, duplifaces, etc.). It is a [know limitation](https://developer.blender.org/T57693) of the current system.

In 2.82 and forward the shadow [system has been reworked](https://developer.blender.org/D5659) to allow this, so either wait it out, try the risks of using an experimental version, or you will have to make your light setup local.